# Slicing 100GB raster datasets

Tags: hard-disk, ssd, raid

## Problem

I'm working with huge brain imaging raster data with four dimensions (x,y,z,t). The dimension sizes are respectively ~1000, ~600, ~20, ~3000 with data stored as uint16, which makes me ~100GB files. To store the data, I have a RAID of 8 8TB hard drives (64TB). Now comes the problem of accessing the data : sometimes I have to take a single (x,y) image, sometimes I have to take all the t's for one xy pixel. Since I can not load all the data in the RAM (I have 64GB), I use memory mapping which means I load the data only when I need it. But it makes the slicing along the z axis is very, very long.

## Question

How can I access and process or visualize my data quickly ?
It would be faster with a RAID of SSD's, but much more expansive. Is there a way to use only one 1TB SSD as the cache for the RAID ?

Comment: Do you know what RAID level you are currently using? There might be a better configuration for your set-up that would give better read performance, but I am not an expert in RAID.

Comment: What is your budget for the SSD? PCI SSDs are going to be much better than the standard SATA SSD, but can be extremely expensive.

Comment: @Cfinley I think it is RAID 0, but it might be RAID 1, I have to check. I did not build it myself.
For the SSDs, we could spend around 1000€, but it is for several computers...